# Ajax with WordPress Functions.php always returns 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I know this question has been asked a lot, so I apologize for any redundancy. However, simply can not seem to make this return a value other than 0. Below is the code that I have included at the bottom of the functions.php within the Twenty-Twelve theme:

```
add_filter( 'views_edit-destination', 'so_13813805_add_button_to_views' );
function so_13813805_add_button_to_views( $views )
{
    $views['my-button'] = '<button id="update-dest-cache" type="button" class="button"             title="Update Destinations Cache" style="margin:5px" onclick="updateDestCache()">Update Destinations Cache</button>';
    $views['my-button'] .= '
        <script type="text/javascript" >
        function updateDestCache() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ajaxurl,
                dataType: "json",
                action: "testAjaxFunction",
                success: function(response){ 
                    alert("Got this from the server: " + response);
                },
                error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){  
                    alert("There was an error: " + errorThrown);  
                },
                timeout: 60000
            });    
        };
        </script>
    ';
    return $views;
}
function testAjax(){
    echo "ANYTHING!!!!";
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_testAjaxFunction', 'testAjax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_testAjaxFunction', 'testAjax' );
```

This code adds a button to the Edit list of a custom post type, and then runs the function upon click. The button shows up, the function runs, the ajax function is called, but 0 is always the response.

Any thoughts on why this continues to occur?

Comment: Please note that removing the `url` variable and the `dataType` variable from the ajax call produces the same results. Also, navigating to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=testAjax` also returns 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had my javascript written incorrectly.

```
function updateDestCache() {
   jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: ajaxurl, 
      data: { action: "testAjaxFunction" }, <---- THIS LINE WAS CHANGED
      success: function(response){ 
         alert("Got this from the server: " + response);
      },
      error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){  
         alert("There was an error: " + errorThrown);  
      },
      timeout: 60000
   });    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ajaxurl` is only defined in your dashboard. If you're using it on the front-end, you should declare it:

```
$admin_url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php');
$views['my-button'] .= '
        <script type="text/javascript" >
        function updateDestCache() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '. $admin_url .', 
                dataType: "json",
                action: "testAjaxFunction",
                success: function(response){ 
                    alert("Got this from the server: " + response);
                },
                error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){  
                    alert("There was an error: " + errorThrown);  
                },
                timeout: 60000
            });    
        };
        </script>
    ';
```

Comment: This is actually an admin-only function within the WordPress CMS. Therefore, the ajaxurl does appear to always be defined. I would also assume that this means that `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_testAjaxFunction', 'testAjax' );` is unnecessary code and can be removed, but since it wasn't working, I figured I would leave it...